# VBA for Excel: Cells(x, y).Value 1004: application-defined or object-defined error: WHY?

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting 1004 error: for lines

```
lstktxt = Cells(lstusefulentry, 12).Value & Cells(lstusefulentry, 13).Value & _
          Cells(lstusefulentry, 14).Value
```

and

```
nextktext = Cells(nextentry, 12).Value & Cells(nextentry, 13).Value & _
            Cells(nextentry, 14).Value
```

Can you think of why? 
Thanks

Edit:

Thanks for the responses. Here is my full macro code.

Any idea where I am introducing the error? nextktext and lstktxt are defined as strings, and lstusefulentry and nextentry are appropriately defined.

```
Sub processTXT()

'
' processTXT Macro
'

'

Dim last As Integer, lstentry As String, lstusefulentry As Integer, lstktxt As 
String, lastknrextract As Variant, lastknr As Integer, lastkidend As 
Integer, lstrelvntrow As Integer, lastkid As String, kid As String, knr As 
Integer, nextrelvntrow As Integer, nextentry As Integer, nextktext As 
String, nextknrextract As Variant, nextkidend As Integer

last = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lstentry = Left(Cells(last, 12).Value, 5)
If lstentry = "VOC5B" Then
 lstusefulentry = (last - 16)
 lstrelvntrow = (lstusefulentry + 8)
Else
 MsgBox "Error!"
End If
lstktxt = Cells(lstusefulentry, 12).Value & Cells(lstusefulentry, 13).Value &
Cells(lstusefulentry, 14).Value
lastknrextract = Mid(lstktxt, 12, 3)
If IsNumeric(lastknrextract) Then
    lastknr = CInt(lastknrextract)
Else
    MsgBox "Error!"
End If
lastkidend = InStr(lstktxt, "end")
lastkid = Trim(Mid(lstktxt, 15, (lastkidend - 15)))
knr = lastknr
kid = lastkid
nextrelvntrow = lstrelvntrow
nextentry = lstusefulentry
nextktext = ""

Do While knr >= 1
 Cells(knr + 3, 18).Value = kid
 Cells(knr + 3, 19).Value = Cells(nextrelvntrow, 14).Value
 nextentry = nextentry - 16
 nextrelvntrow = nextentry + 8
 nextktext = Cells(nextentry, 12).Value & Cells(nextentry, 13).Value & 
 Cells(nextentry, 14).Value
nextknrextract = Mid(nextktext, 12, 3)
knr = CInt(nextknrextract)
nextkidend = InStr(nextktext, "end")
kid = Trim(Mid(nextktext, 15, (nextkidend - 15)))
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the sub-procedure or function? You've got quotation marks around the parts of the statement which I imagine don't want to be there.

Comment: What are the values of `lstusefulentry` and `nextentry` ?  P.S. I formatted your code - please format any additional code you add.

Comment: judging from your tittle :
VBA for Excel: Cells(x, y).Value ,   i'd say x and y are reversed :   in your example x is row, and y column, right ?

Answer (score 0):

`lstusefulentry` must be an **Integer** or **Long** variable with a value greater than zero and less than or equal to **Rows.Count**